# Swift For Loops using Closed Range

Tags: swift, for-loop, integer

I have a `for` loop and want to access the 'current' index. Xcode is giving me irritating errors.

```
for k in [1...map.dates.count-1]
{
    map.returns.append((map.closingPrices[k]-map.closingPrices[k-1])/map.closingPrices[k-1])
}
```

So what I'm basically doing is `for k in [1..10]`, calculate the return (b-a)/a where b and a are contiguous elements in some array (`closingPrices`).

The compiler has no issue with me using `k` to access `closingPrices` but it gets upset when I use `k-1` because k is not an integer, it is a `CountableClosedRange<Int>`.

Error says

> Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to types CountableClosedRange and Int.

So - simple question - how do I rewrite my code to access the integer value of k and substract 1 from it and not get a compiler error.

Comment: You probably want `for k in 1...map.dates.count-1 {...}`, without the square brackets.

Comment: Yes sorry I just for the syntax wrong there! Much thanks. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: You can also say `for k in 1..<map.dates.count` to make it look a little cleaner, though it is the exact same thing as `1...map.dates.count-1`.

Comment: Or `map.returns = zip(map.closingPrices, map.closingPrices.dropFirst()).map { ($1 - $0)/$0 }` – No indices needed :)

Comment: Love the one-liner there!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
[1...map.dates.count-1]
```

returns **array** containing a single range, so your loop counter is not an integer as you expect, but a range object. Just remove square brackets and you should be fine:

```
for k in 1...map.dates.count-1
{
    map.returns.append((map.closingPrices[k]-map.closingPrices[k-1])/map.closingPrices[k-1])
}
```

Comment: If you are subtracting `-1` then you could directly use `1 ..< map.dates.count`. Or something like `map.dates.indices.dropFirst()`.